# How relationship works in coreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, relationship

I know how to create a relationship in coredata,but i do not know how it works.

Eg.:

Employee:
  name
  id

Department:
  name

I can create a relationship(one to many) between 'Department' and 'Employee',and when i fetch 'Department', i will also get employees automatically.

If no relationship,I will create a field(employeeId) in department, and join 'Employee' table.

I do not know coredata how to get the correct employees by relationship.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explore what is the entity is from the real sqlite file.

For example
I have this relationship
[image]

When I add three record,I use SliteBrowser to View the SQLite file
It have five tables
[image]

The ZDEPARTMENT Table
[image]
The ZEMPLOYEE Table
[image]

Note what I selected in ZEMPLOYEE,it save the id of `department` in ZDEPARTMENT,so it is quite clear how core data relationship works.

NOTE:

- Z_PK is the unique in SQLite Table
- Z_ENT is their entity id  same as the one listed in the Z_PRIMARYKEY table

Comment: So coredata generate automatically  Z_PK for every entity, and when we create a relationship,it  add a field(foreign key) and insert the value  automatically?

Comment: Yes,core data will handle relationship for you,you just need to focus on OO programming.You may find more details on document.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch correct employe using NSPredicate in your NSFetchRequest.
NSPredicate is similar like where clause used in Database.
Please check this:  [Use NSPredicate in CoreData Fetch](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/09/22/filtering-core-data-result-sets-with-nspredicate/) 
and [NSPredicate in CoreData](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/)

Hope this will helps you.